# HTTPS only for the login page - Is it recommended?

Tags: security, http, authentication, https, session-cookies

I have a website which requires user to login. And since all the content is not available over https, we have decided that we will use https only for the login page.

All other data's submitted on the page are not sensitive and needn't be encrypted.

Can this approach compromise user's login credentials? Having all other pages on http - can an attacker get access to the credentials from the user session cookies?

I could see many sites having this approach so I think it might be safe - but would like to understand the technicalities behind it.

Comment: "All other data's submitted on the page are not sensitive" says who? I care about my privacy. Also I care about being able to be sure I am indeed on the site I htink I am.

Comment: Also if you are using non https only cookies it will leak out just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having https **only** on the login page **is insecure**:

- It means you don't use HSTS, which is the only protection against SSLSrip
- It means an attacker can replace on your http pages your link to the login page by something else (like a popin that submit credentials to his server)
- Once the user is connected, the cookie **must** have the secure attribute (it's really easy to steal cookies without. see firesheep)

**The only secure way is to use https in all pages of your domain, use HSTS and redirect all http requests to https.**

> Can this approach compromise user's login credentials? Having all other pages on http - can an attacker get access to the credentials from the user session cookies?

An attacker can steal the session cookie, so he probably can do a lot of harm (depending of your security measures, change the password, the email, extract personnal data...) and he can simulate disconnection and ask again for passwords on http webpages.

> I could see many sites having this approach so I think it might be safe

No, it's not. They probably have website too big to turn on https everywhere, so they did what they could to limit damages. (Or they are just lazy)

Answer (score -2):

1. HTTPS could be implemented only for login page provided Secure flag is enabled for application.
   Secure flag will prevent transmission of cookies in plaintext.
   Failure to use the "secure" flag enables an attacker to get the session cookie by tricking the user's browser into submitting a request to an Non-HTTPS page on the site.
2. HTTPS should be used for login page and all other authenticated pages. HTTPS on login page passes the credentials in encrypted format but all other authorized requests travels in unencrytped format means session ID will be transmitted in plaintext if any of the HTTP request uses the session ID.

Best way is to use HTTPS for all the pages which makes sure complete data transmits in encrypted format.

Ref: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: "HTTPS could be implemented only for login page provided Secure flag is enabled for application" is wrong : if you have the secure flag (which you should!) then pages that require authentication (other than the login page) must be https or they will not receive the authentication cookie.